# System Requirements for E-Commerce Application with SSL bigger than 40 bits

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, hardware, requirements

I need to define the system requirements hardware and software for building a E-Commerce Web application with SSL (more than 40 bits). I have no experience with SSL, so i have no idea how to configure or what apache version do i need. This are my thoughts:

**Operating System Linux**
Web Server: Apache
DBMS: MySQL 5.0 or bigger
Application Server: Tomcat 5.5 or bigger
Java 1.5 or bigger

**Memory:   576 MB**
Disk Space:  10 GB 
Data Transfer Allowance: 75GB
Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 270

Does anyone know which Apache/Tomcat version do i need to support SSL (more than 40 bits)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All versions support `40 bit` SSL. 40 bit is better known as faking encryption.